# Meteor stuck at "starting app on android device"

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

```
meteor run android-device -p 8099 --verbose
Getting installed version for platform android in Cordova project
Checking Cordova requirements for platform Android
[[[[[ ~/WebstormProjects/todo-list ]]]]]      

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
Local package version is up-to-date: autopublish@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: autoupdate@1.2.4
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-compiler@5.8.24_1
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-runtime@0.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: base64@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: binary-heap@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze@2.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-html-templates@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-tools@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: boilerplate-generator@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: caching-compiler@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: caching-html-compiler@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: callback-hook@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: check@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-client@1.2.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-common@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-server@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: deps@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: diff-sequence@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript@0.1.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript-runtime@0.2.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ejson@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: es5-shim@4.1.14
Local package version is up-to-date: fastclick@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: fourseven:scss@3.4.1
Local package version is up-to-date: geojson-utils@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: hot-code-push@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: html-tools@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: htmljs@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: http@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: id-map@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: insecure@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: jquery@1.11.4
Local package version is up-to-date: launch-screen@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: livedata@1.0.15
Local package version is up-to-date: logging@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor@1.1.10
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor-base@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: minifiers@1.1.7
Local package version is up-to-date: minimongo@1.0.10
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-experience@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-status-bar@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo-id@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: npm-mongo@1.4.39_1
Local package version is up-to-date: observe-sequence@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: ordered-dict@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: promise@0.5.1
Local package version is up-to-date: random@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-dict@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-var@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: reload@1.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: retry@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: routepolicy@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: session@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars-compiler@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: standard-minifiers@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: templating@1.1.5
Local package version is up-to-date: templating-tools@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: tracker@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ui@1.0.8 
Local package version is up-to-date: underscore@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: url@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp@1.2.3
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp-hashing@1.0.5
Preparing Cordova project from app bundle     
Copying resources for mobile apps             
Writing new config.xml                        
Preparing Cordova project for platform Android

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on
         the same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
Running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:8099/     
Running: /Users/shasn/WebstormProjects/todo-list/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/shasn/WebstormProjects/todo-list/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
   Starting app on Android Device            /
```

I have done

- a meteor reset
- removed and connected the android device again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out it was downloading gradle. Leaving it untouched and running for sometime actually deployed the app on my android.